# Display login block and registration block

Tags: drupal

I am trying to create a front page for a drupal page, but I can't quite figure out what php code would allow me to display both login and signup (registration) blocks on the front page.
The front page will look like Twitter or Linkedin.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal block for signing in and signing up are the same. In the blocks area of the admin, the block is titled: "User login"

You could assign it to only show up on `<front>` (for the front page), and move it to whatever region you want.

Comment: ChrisLTD thanks for your replay, but what I probably failed to mention is that the front page is a customized one which will require that I programmably add the drupal block for signing in                    the Front--page.tpl.php, but I can't tell how to do it. I've seen some suggestions such as this <?php
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print render($block['content']);
?>  but it has not worked for me so far.

Comment: If you can't get that to work, you could trying adding a new region, then using what I mentioned above. The process for adding a new region in Drupal 7 is outlined here: http://megadrupal.com/blog/add-new-regions-in-drupal-7-themes

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically display login form, you need to do this:

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form("user_login")));
```

To programmatically display signup form, you need to do this:

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form("user_register_form")));
```

put those somewhere in your customized front page.